# How do I transform a 2 column dataframe into a Series--Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I tried dataframe.iloc[:] , but it returned a dataframe. I also tried dataframe.T.squeeze() but no luck. Those two only works for 1 column dataframe. Any ideas would really be helpful.

Update: I later learned that this is not possible since a series has only one value column. The only way around this is to set one of the columns as index (provided that column is unique tho). Don't want to delete the post since others I contributed answers and ideas to it.

Comment: `pd.Series` is a single column of `pd.DataFrame`. If you want to transform dataframe into series, you need to specify what output do you expect

Comment: [`df[0].append(df[1])`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.append.html)?

Comment: If you're fine with throwing out the index (which makes me question why you are using a DataFrame), you can use `pd.Series(df.values.ravel('F'))`.

Comment: @Kopytok that was helpful. I didn't know the difference. I solved it.

Answer (score -1):

You can concatenate the elements of these columns row-wise into lists and then convert the result to a `pandas.Series`:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]], columns=['c1', 'c2'])

In [3]: df
Out[4]:
   c1  c2
0   1   2
1   3   4

In [5]:s = pd.Series(df[['c1', 'c2']].values.tolist())

In [6]:s
Out[7]:
0    [1, 2]
1    [3, 4]
dtype: object
```